# How do you exit from a void function in C++?

Tags: c++

How can you prematurely exit from a function without returning a value if it is a void function? I have a void method that needs to not execute its code if a certain condition is true. I really don't want to have to change the method to actually return a value.

Comment: Despite that this is a really simple question, I upvoted because I had the same problem when I wrote my first C program :)

Comment: @itsbunnies: As mentioned elsewhere, there are no programming questions too simple to be asked on SO.  If you had trouble with it, so has someone else in the past and so will someone else in the future.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: What about the first program who *ever* had that problem? Who had that problem in *his* past? ;-)

Comment: just had this question myself :)

Comment: Note you can always rewrite a function to always return at the bottom, which is a structured programming principle (one point of entry, one point of exit),

Comment: +1 @MalcolmMcLean some coding rules like MISRA would never accept more than 1 return in a function, so I stronlgy agree.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Use a return statement!

```
return;
```

or

```
if (condition) return;
```

You don't need to (and can't) specify any values, if your method returns `void`.

Comment: Even more to the point: you must NOT specify any return value if your method returns void.

Comment: Aha, so when we write return; not returning anything means returning void itself eh? void means nothing anyway!! Hmm I get it now.

Comment: @quantum321 I think the return value is technically undefined, not void but thinking of it as "void" is useful.

Comment: @Dr.PersonPersonII by 'if your method returns "void"', I meant the purely syntactical view of the method's return type declared as `void`.

Technically, the method does not return anything. which is different from returning undefined.

Comment: Actually you can write `return void()` too :)

Answer (score 15):

You mean like this?

```
void foo ( int i ) {
    if ( i < 0 ) return; // do nothing
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
void foo() {
  /* do some stuff */
  if (!condition) {
    return;
  }
}
```

You can just use the return keyword just like you would in any other function.