# gravity attraction between masses

Tags: c, function, pointers, double

Why does my program keep calculating the same force? I'm using the formula correctly however I'm not sure why I keep getting a force of 127 dynes. Any help would be appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
const double gravity_constant = 6.673;
void force_calculate(double a, double b, double c, double d);
void input(double *a, double *b, double *c);
void display(double a, double b, double c, double d);
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    double mass_1 = 0;
    double mass_2 = 0;
    double distance = 0;
    double force = 0;

    input(&mass_1, &mass_2, &distance);
    force = force_calculate(mass_1, mass_2, distance, force);
    display(mass_1, mass_2, distance, force);

    return 0;
}

void force_calculate(double a, double b, double c, double d)
{
    d = (gravity_constant*a*b)/(c*c);
    return;
}
void input(double *a, double *b, double *c)
{
    printf("What is the first mass in grams?\n");
    scanf("%lf", a);
    printf("What is the second mass in grams?\n");
    scanf("%lf", b);
    printf("What is the distance between the two masses in centimeters\n");
    scanf("%lf", c);
}
void display(double a, double b, double c, double d)
{
    printf("%fg is the first mass\n", a);
    printf("%fg is the second mass\n", b);
    printf("%fcm is the distance between the two masses\n", c);
    printf("%f is the force in dynes between both masses\n", d);
    return;
}
```

Comment: When you compiled `force = force_calculate(mass_1, mass_2, distance, force);`, your compiler should have warned you loudly about the fact that you're attempting to use the non-existent return value of a `void` function. Either you need to turn up the warning level of your compiler, or you need to get into the habit of not ignoring warnings.

Comment: ***A general comment***. (or perhaps just a fun fact...) A function prototyped as `void func(,,)`, is not required to have a `return` statement within the `{...}` brackets.  It _can_ have one (or many), and is sometimes useful, particularly if you would like to exit _before_ the remaining statements in the function block have executed, such as when an error condition is encountered, or when certain conditions have been met, such that execution of following statements is no longer necessary, or desired.  In the case of your code, they are not necessary as there are no following statements.

Answer (score 1):

**First method**:

Pass `force` by reference. Change the definition of `force` to

```
void force_calculate(double a, double b, double c, double *d)
{
    *d = (gravity_constant*a*b)/(c*c);
}
```

and call it like this

```
force_calculate(mass_1, mass_2, distance, &force);
```

**Second method:**

You could simply return the value from `force_calculate`

```
double force_calculate(double a, double b, double c, double d)
{
    d = (gravity_constant*a*b)/(c*c);
    return d;
}
```

Comment: C does not support pass-by-reference. Your code is not passing the variable `d` by reference, it is passing the _address_ of `d` by _value_.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Yes, strictly speaking it does not. It utilizes pointer mechanism to pass the address by value. But it is commonly referred to as "pass by reference" in books.

Comment: Oh? Which books? I've never seen it referred to as "pass by reference" in any books. And, considering that C++ does support a "pass by reference" mechanism in addition to the ability to pass addresses by value, I would have to say that any such book is simply wrong.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson I have seen many books where they do. Have a look at IBM [documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr233.htm)

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Also, since you are jumping to conclusions have a look at the tag. It says `C` not `C++`. They are different languages.

Comment: Yes, they are different languages. They are fairly similar in some ways, though, and both provide, with identical syntax, the ability to pass the address of a variable by value. One of these languages also provides the ability to pass references to objects, which is a distinctly difference thing from passing pointers to objects, and uses a different syntax.

Comment: Thank you for providing that link to IBM's documentation for the XL C/C++ compiler. I have reviewed the link you provided, and surrounding material, and I stand by my previous statement that this is wrong. This IBM documentation is not only using incorrect terminology, it is describing the relevant concepts in an incorrect and inaccurate manner.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Thank you for aligning to my point of view. That's what I am saying that it is not strictly true. However, in `C`, this  is referred to as "pass by reference" mechanism in many places.

Comment: And all I'm saying is that regardless of who's doing it, it is _incorrect_ when talking about C to refer to any of these mechanisms as "pass by reference".

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Yes, I get that. You have downvoted me for what I agree with despite presenting proof for my terminology the existence of which you initially denied. So, please excuse me as it's almost 03:00 in my country and I am going to sleep. Thanks for the conversation.

Comment: I downvoted you for conflating pass-address-by-value with pass-by-reference, because no matter how many other people are doing it, it's still inaccurate, and incorrect.

Comment: +1 Just because I enjoyed that you did not simply back down from a contentious myopic point of view.  Good for you!  By the way, I have also heard it referred to as _pass by reference_ for many years (what a tedious argument)  Just Google the phrase...  ***[1](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr233.htm)***, ***[2](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/)***, ***[3](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/)***, and the list goes on.

Answer (score 1):

You should be returning the value so that it can be assigned (make sure it is the proper type as well). Also, you can remove the use of force here because it is the result of the calculation.

```
force = force_calculate(mass_1, mass_2, distance);
...
double force_calculate(double a, double b, double c)
{
 return (gravity_constant*a*b)/(c*c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that return type of your `force_calculate()` function is `void` and you are assigning it to `force` in `main()`
Your function definition should be

```
void force_calculate(double a, double b, double c, double *d)
{
    *d = (gravity_constant*a*b)/(c*c);
}
```

Do not forgot to change its function prototype. And function call should be

```
force_calculate(mass_1, mass_2, distance, &force);
```

Comment: You can return from any place in a function that is declared to return void. http://stackoverflow.com/a/346616/2293156 and he is not returning anything

Answer (score 1):

Running this program gives following runtime error to me.

**d.c:15:11: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be**

I think, this could fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
const double gravity_constant = 6.673;
double force_calculate(double a, double b, double c);
void input(double *a, double *b, double *c);
void display(double a, double b, double c, double d);
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    double mass_1 = 0;
    double mass_2 = 0;
    double distance = 0;
    double force = 0;

    input(&mass_1, &mass_2, &distance);
    force = force_calculate(mass_1, mass_2, distance);
    display(mass_1, mass_2, distance, force);

    return 0;
}

double force_calculate(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double force;
    force = (gravity_constant*a*b)/(c*c);
    return force;
}
void input(double *a, double *b, double *c)
{
    printf("What is the first mass in grams?\n");
    scanf("%lf", a);
    printf("What is the second mass in grams?\n");
    scanf("%lf", b);
    printf("What is the distance between the two masses in centimeters\n");
    scanf("%lf", c);
}
void display(double a, double b, double c, double d)
{
    printf("%fg is the first mass\n", a);
    printf("%fg is the second mass\n", b);
    printf("%fcm is the distance between the two masses\n", c);
    printf("%f is the force in dynes between both masses\n", d);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Laid out very clearly and easy to understand.  You could have simplified `force_calculate()` by simply returning the calculation:  `return (gravity_constant*a*b)/(c*c);`.  But that's just a nit.  Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `force_calculate` to return nothing (void), but in main method, you call it like this:

```
force = force_calculate(mass_1, mass_2, distance, force);
```

i.e., you are returning a double.

Change you force_calculate to this declaration:

```
double force_calculate(double a, double b, double c);
```

and force_calculate to this definition:

```
double force_calculate(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return (gravity_constant*a*b)/(c*c);
}
```